# WPF call method when property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

In C#, how can a method be called when a property changes (both method and property belong to the same class)?

e.g.,

```
class BrowserViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public List<TreeViewModel> Status { get; private set; }
    public string Conditions { get; private set; }

    #endregion // Properties

    // i'd like to call this method when Status gets updated
    void updateConditions
    {
         /* Conditions = something depending on the TreeViewItem select status */
    }
}
```

Binding

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="StatusTree"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=OneTime}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}"
/>
```

**Use-Case** (if you are curious)

The property `Status` is bound to a `TreeView` control in the xaml. When it is updated, I'd like to call a method that updates the property `Conditions`. This property is bound to a `TextBox` in the xaml.

I'm new to Eventing in C#, so am a little lost.

### Edit

1. class `TreeViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. `Conditions` is updated by getting the `IsChecked` Value from the `TreeView`.
3. The size of the Status List never changes. When a TreeViewItem is selected/unselected the TreeViewModel changes.
4. TreeViewModel source (FooViewModel on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=28306) page)
5. Binding code above.
6. Didn't have to change Binding Mode for `IsChecked`.

   ```
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
           x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}"
           >
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <!-- These elements are bound to a TreeViewModel object. -->
               <CheckBox
                   Focusable="False" 
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   />
               <ContentPresenter 
                   Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" 
                   Margin="2,0"
                   />
               </StackPanel>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   ```

Comment: Call your method in the property setter.

Comment: I don't get it. In the `set` method of `Conditions` you can simply have it call `updateConditions`, though it seems the only thing you want to do in `updateConditions` is to set `Conditions`. What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you want `updateConditions` to fire whenever an `item` is added/removed/changed in your list, not if the list reference itself changes.

Since you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged within your TreeViewModel, I think you'll want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a plain `List<T>`. Check it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

```
class BrowserViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Status { get; private set; }
    public string Conditions { get; private set; }

    #endregion // Properties

    // i'd like to call this method when Status gets updated
    void updateConditions
    {
         /* Conditions = something */
    }

    public BrowserViewModel()
    {
        Status = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();
        Status.CollectionChanged += (e, v) => updateConditions();
    }
}
```

CollectionChanged will fire whenever an item is added/removed/changed. As far as I know, it will consider it "changed" when its reference changes or any of its properties are changed (which is notified through `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

Just checked it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx

> ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Event
>   Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

`ObservableCollection<T>` resides in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace, in `System.dll` assembly.

Comment: I see. What happens if you change this in your model: `public List<FooViewModel> Children { get; private set; }` to an ObservableCollection as well?

Comment: Let's say I'm not immediately concerned about the children. Based on your code, I'm unable to get the method `updateConditions()` called when I check/uncheck the parent (`IsChecked` property) of the `TreeViewModel`. Something else is missing I guess...

Comment: I think you need to set `Mode` to `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource`, not OneWay. From msdn: `OneWay updates the target property only when the source property changes.` You need to update the source property (your model) when the target property changes.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. The binding mode default depends on the property of the control. Some user-editable properties such as TextBox.Text, ComboBox.Text, MenuItem.IsChecked, etc, seem to have TwoWay as their default Mode value.